# Add class to toggled checkbox parent on Wordpress

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, wordpress

I'm currently working on a Wordpress site and I can't get the active checkbox JS code to add a `checked` class to my parent element.

The snippet works perfectly fine, but why does it not work on my Wordpress site?

```js
$(":checkbox").on('click', function() {
  $(this).parent('span').toggleClass("checked");
});
```

```css
span.cb-style input[type=checkbox] {
  cursor: pointer;
  background: 0 0;
  position: relative;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  float: left;
  border: none;
  opacity: 0;
}

span.cb-style {
  cursor: pointer;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 18px;
  height: 18px;
  position: relative;
  top: 4px;
  border: 3px solid #ddd;
  background: #fff;
  visibility: visible;
  margin-right: 10px
}

span.cb-style:hover {
  background: #ddd
}

.checked {
  background-color: #ff0000!important;
  border-color: #ff0000!important;
}

.checked:after {
  font-family: "Font Awesome 5 Free";
  content: 'x';
  color: white;
  position: absolute;
  font-size: 25pt;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  top: 0;
  margin: -75% auto;
  pointer-events: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="tnp-field tnp-field-checkbox tnp-field-privacy">
  <span class="cb-style">
    <input type="checkbox" name="ny" required="" class="tnp-privacy" id="tnp-privacy">
  </span>
  <label for="tnp-privacy">
    <a target="_blank" href="#">Checkbox Sample Text Bla.</a>
  </label>
</div>
```

Comment: If it's working in the snippet but not on your site then either you've not included jQuery.js in the page properly, or your running the jQuery code before the DOM has loaded. Check the console for errors, and try moving the `<script>` tag to just before `</body>`

Comment: unfortunately that did not work.. jquery migrate ver.1.4.1 is disabled and I added jquery to the head and the script to the footer or right aboth the closing body tag, but nothing changed

Comment: Are there any errors in the console?

Comment: What exactly is not working? Class `.checked` not assigned?

Comment: yes class checked is not assigning,
Console error:

`$(":checkbox").on('click', function() {
      $(this).parent('span').toggleClass("checked");
    });
   **});** <- Parse Error `

Comment: Okay nevermind i've noticed the code wasn't actually placed at the very bottom before the body tag closes.. thx guys! and sorry for the inconvenience